# Layout Constraint in iOS Xcode 7

Tags: ios9, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

[image]

I would like to close the image container and view container. I don't want any spacing between these views. Firstly, I add "View Container" and then put "Image" into it. Then, I add another "View Container" and put some label text into it. 
I made some constraints into these views as I mention in attached image.
But the two containers are not close and show some constraint errors. 
Please help me to solve the problems.

Comment: hello @May , your question is not understand please give more description and details.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use pin

[image]

Select the top container. pin it to top,left and right. Also set the height constriant.

Then select the image view in side the top container. Pin it to all 4 sides.

Do the same for bottom container.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bottom constraints for both the views. Let us think the 1st view with image is view1 and 2nd view with label is view2.

1. Ctrl+Drag from view1 to view2 and select vertical spacing. Check the constraint and change it to 0 if it is not.
2. Fix the heights of both views. Do not add bottom constraint for view2 as it will lead to conflict.